# Selecting records from access by visual basic

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ms-access

I am asked to make a program that has a database using visual basic and access ,,this is the first time i use vb so am not very familiar with it. The program should take information about schools visits to technical support department and store it in the database. The user of the program can view all records,records of a specific school and can be able to choose one record and print a report of it. I did the first parts which are adding records, veiwing all the records and finding the records belonging to one school by searching it name but I am stuck at how to let the user choose one of these records and making a report of it :( ,, could anyone kindly suggest an idea of how to make one record selectable and when selected, a report is filled with this record info. Am using visual studio 2008 and microsoft access 2003.

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access, you can open a report with a Where condition:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "ReportName", acViewPreview, , "NumericIdOnReport=" & IdOnForm
```

[OpenReport Method [Access 2003 VBA Language Reference]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220304%28v=office.11%29.aspx)